# Metro Styles in resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am trying to style my WPF application with Mahapps Metro. I have added the all the needed .xaml files in my `MergedDictionary` in the App.xaml. If I write the following in a view file,

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}"/>
```

it works, i.e., the button is styled in the `SquareButtonStyle` style. But if I instead add the following in my own resource dictionary,

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

I get an error message,

> Setting of the property
>   "System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent" has caused an
>   exception.

(my transation of the German error message). So how can I style all buttons, e.g., with `SquareButtonStyle` without having to do that on each button individually?

EDIT: Here is my app.xaml (the last dictionary, ResourceDic.xaml, is my own one where the above code is):

```
<Application xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MGM8" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:MGM8_BootStrapper p7:Key="bootstrapper" xmlns:p7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Style` property can't be set inside `Style` of any element.**

Just declare your style at root level(a root resource Dictionary or App.xmal resources). Just create the style with `TargetType` `Button` don't give any key to it. it will be applied to all the buttons in the app.

for ex:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonStyle}" >
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,1" />
    </Style>
```

So above is extending your `SquareButtonStyle` for your application for all buttons(only if defined at root level).

**Update:**

You have to use following in your own Resource Dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="SquareButtonStyle dictionary"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Then only you can create a button style based on `SquareButtonStyle` in your ResourceDictionary.

Comment: And I dont want to declare the style myself. `SquareButtonStyle` is a predefined style of Mahapps Metro.

Comment: sorry, see my updated answer. you can use baseon property of style

Comment: Tried `BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonStyle}"` and `BasedOn="{DynmicResource SquareButtonStyle}"` - I still get the error ...

Comment: can you give SquareButtonStyle to me?

Comment: Have you removed Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle} from your button definition ?

Comment: @KyloRen: Also note that `SquareButtonStyle` does work when directly applied to a button!

Comment: i mean you must be merging the dictionary of SquareButtonStyle into your app. Can you give the code where are you merging the dictionary and where are you defining your new style? Cause the error looks like this.

Comment: @EluciusFTW but in the question you have mentioned that when directly apply to a button "it works".

Comment: @KyloRen: Edited question and added App.xaml.

Comment: @KyloRen: Yes, it works, but I don't want to do it on tons of buttons! I want to set it for all buttons as default in the resource dictionary ...

Comment: @EluciusFTW it's the problem of ResourceDictionary merging. see my update in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103116/discussion-between-eluciusftw-and-kylo-ren).

Comment: @EluciusFTW did you reinstalled the package?